# Echo cancellation with Core audio APIs

Tags: windows, api, echo, core-audio, aec

Did anybody try cancelling echo with Windows Core audio API? I wonder how good it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is done in the webrtc package offered by google. Checkout the core audio driver for windows (audio_device_core_win.cc).  For devices that support the feature it's worked quite well for me.